# Polynomial Division: where does the remainder go?

Tags: polynomials

If

*P(x) = x <sup>4</sup> + 4x <sup>3</sup> - 14x <sup>2</sup> + 36x + 45*

is divided by *x + 5*

and the remainder that I found is **-1250**, would it go at the end of the quotient? Like this:

x <sup>3</sup> - 9x <sup>2</sup> - 59x + 259 -  ***1250***  ?

*<sub>*...forgot how to do this stuff :\*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do not trust your memory, think of division from first principles. How does *integer* division work? If you try to divide $\frac{7}{5}$ you know that the quotient is $1$, but how do you find the **remainder**? You multiply $1\cdot 5=5$ but you still need $2$ to reach $7$. In other words:
$$ 7 = 1 \cdot 5 + 2$$
or, in general, if you divide $\frac{N}{D}$ obtaining the quotient $Q$ and the remainder $R$, it is true than:
$$ N = Q \cdot D + R$$

Now, if you divide both sides of this equation by $D$ you recover the original fraction:
$$\frac{N}{D}=Q+\frac{R}{D}$$

It works the same with polynomials, so in your case:
$$\frac{P(x)}{x+5}=Q(x)+\frac{R}{x+5}$$
where $R=-360$ as other answers have pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Since $P(-5)=-360$ and since$$\frac{P(x)+360}{x+5}=x^3-x^2-9x+81,$$you have $P(x)=(x^3-x^2-9x+81)(x+5)+360$.

Answer (score 2):

$\,P(x)=q(x).g(x)+r(x)$
:.
    $(x^4+4x^3-14x^2+36x+45) = (x^3-x^2-9x+81).(x+5) + (-360)$.

I hope you asked for this, otherwise pardon.

Alternatively use remainder theorem...
to find remainder only.
$P(-5)=-360.$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: the right result should be $${x}^{3}-{x}^{2}-9\,x+81-360\, \left( x+5 \right) ^{-1}$$the remainder is given by $-360$